# How do I create a point with an SRID in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, spatial, mysql-8.0

MySQL supports using [`ST_PointFromText`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-pointfromtext) to construct a point with an SRID,

> - `ST_PointFromText(wkt[, srid [, options]])`
>
>   Constructs a Point value using its WKT representation and SRID.

This assumes the input is Well-Known Text (WKT). How do I construct a point with latitude and longitude as [doubles (or floating point types)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## MySQL 8.0+

MySQL supports [`Point(x,y)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_point) which is a GIS function that constructs a point. With MySQL 8.0 and newer, you can further assign an SRID to that point with [`ST_SRID(srid)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-general-property-functions.html#function_st-srid)

```
SELECT ST_SRID( Point(0,0), 4326);
```

This is a relatively new feature implemented in MySQL 8.0 with [#WL8543](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8543). MariaDB does not support it.

In PostGIS, you would use,

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(0,0), 4326);
```

In MariaDB, your only option is,

```
ST_PointFromText(wkt[, srid [, options]])
```