# MySQL Geo Spatial Query is very slow although index is used

Tags: mysql, performance, spatial, query-performance

I need to fetch records from a InnoDb Table by distance (must not be exactly) and sort by distance.
The table has 10 million records.

My best time is so far 8 sec (3 sec without order by distance), which make this not usable. How I could improve this?

I have a point column defined as SRID 4326.
I'm using MySQL 8.0.12.

```
SELECT mp.hash_id, 
ROUND(ST_Distance(ST_SRID(POINT(8.53955, 47.37706), 4326), mp.geo_pt), 2) AS distance
  FROM member_profile mp 
  WHERE
    MBRCONTAINS(ST_GeomFromText(
      CONCAT('POLYGON((', ST_X(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831, ' ',
        ST_Y(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831, ',',
        ST_X(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) + 0.43415340086831, ' ',
        ST_Y(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831, ',',
        ST_X(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) + 0.43415340086831, ' ',
        ST_Y(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) + 0.43415340086831, ',',
        ST_X(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831, ' ',
        ST_Y(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) + 0.43415340086831, ',',
        ST_X(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831, ' ',
        ST_Y(POINT (8.53955, 47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831, ')) ')
           , 4326), geo_pt)
-- ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (8.53955 47.37706)', 4326), mp.geo_pt) <= 25000 -- need 16 sec
-- order by distance -- need 8 sec with MBRContains, 100 sec with ST_Distance
LIMIT 50;
```

A spatial Index was created:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX geo_pt_index ON mp (geo_pt);
```

EXPLAIN shows me that my geo_pt Index is used.

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
key_buffer_size = 1G
secure-file-priv = ""
```

This Server is only allocated for this database, no load on it (except when I execute a Query). There is no IOPS bottleneck. 
innodb_buffer_pool_size is sized to hold the whole dataset in Memory.

Server Instance has 16 GB Memory, uses fast NVMe SSD (There is no IOPS bottleneck). The Server only hosts this one Database and has except the Querys no load. 30% of Disk is used.

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` Output: https://pastebin.com/EMeNL8yT

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` Output: https://pastebin.com/yxzYn10E

MySQL Tuner Output: https://pastebin.com/NRWFQDMQ

I have today updated from 8.0.11 to 8.0.12 but followed mostly all related proposal of earlier MySQL Tuner Recommendations. The MySQL update was done regarding some fixed Bug with Spatial Search before the speed was the same.

SHOW WARNINGS (after Query execute):

```
Level,Code,Message
Note,1003,/* select#1 */ select `***`.`mp`.`member_id` AS `member_id`,round(st_distance(st_pointfromtext('POINT(8.53955 47.37706)',4326),`***`.`mp`.`geo_pt`),2) AS `distance` from `***`.`member_profile` `mp` where mbrcontains(<cache>(st_geomfromtext(concat('POLYGON((',(st_x(point(8.53955,47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831),' ',(st_y(point(8.53955,47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831),',',(st_x(point(8.53955,47.37706)) + 0.43415340086831),' ',(st_y(point(8.53955,47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831),',',(st_x(point(8.53955,47.37706)) + 0.43415340086831),' ',(st_y(point(8.53955,47.37706)) + 0.43415340086831),',',(st_x(point(8.53955,47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831),' ',(st_y(point(8.53955,47.37706)) + 0.43415340086831),',',(st_x(point(8.53955,47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831),' ',(st_y(point(8.53955,47.37706)) - 0.43415340086831),')) '),4326)),`***`.`mp`.`geo_pt`) order by `distance` limit 50
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,
key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,mp,\N,range,geo_pt_index,geo_pt_index,34,\N,23,100.00,Using where; Using filesort
```

CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `member_profile` (
  `member_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash_id` varchar(32)
        CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `geo_pt` point NOT NULL /*!80003 SRID 4326 */,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash_id` (`hash_id`),
  SPATIAL KEY `geo_pt_index` (`geo_pt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10498210
            DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

SHOW INDEX FROM:

```
Table,Non_unique,Key_name,Seq_in_index,Column_name,Collation,
Cardinality,Sub_part,
Packed,Null,Index_type,Comment,Index_comment,Visible

member_profile,0,PRIMARY,1,member_id,A,9936492,\N,\N,,BTREE,,,YES
member_profile,0,hash_id,1,hash_id,A,9936492,\N,\N,YES,BTREE,,,YES
member_profile,1,geo_pt_index,1,geo_pt,A,9936492,32,\N,,SPATIAL,,,YES
```

Comment: don't construct points like that https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/213814/2639

Comment: Also how many rows are returned  prior-to/without the sort/limit.

Comment: @EvanCarroll 79901 rows are returned without Limit. changed query to use ST_SRID.

Comment: So essentially, you're having to (a) sort through 10 million rows on an index, (b)  retrieve 79,901 rows, and (c) calculate the distance of those 79,901 rows to arbitrary point (d) sort those 79,901 rows by the distance. Of course that takes time, especially when the database doesn't support KNN.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I understand, seems time to put elasticsearch into the game.

Comment: Or just use a real database.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Is PostgreSQL classified as "real database"?  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214782/postgresql-geo-spatial-query-is-slow

Comment: @nenad007  Could we Skype for 5 minutes? view profile, Network Profile, for contact info, including Skype ID.  AFTER you look at this url?  https://www.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL   
and this url as well.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168380/use-mysql-spatial-extensions-to-select-points-inside-circle
 Thanks

Comment: @nenad007 did you figure out the fix?

Answer (score 5):

"I have a point column defined as SRID 4326. I'm using MySQL 8.0.12."

I have a similar problem and changing the SRID to 0 improves performance significantly. I don't know if the side effect are unbearable for you, but at least you should try! Dont forget the other order of the lat and lon if you do that ;)

KR
Pete

Comment: By doing this I was able to make a simple WHERE ST_Contains(shape, point) query 10x faster (~0.34 ms to ~0.025) on a table with ~700,000 complex Polygons/Multipolygons and an index.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
max_connect_errors=10  # from 100, why give a hacker/cracker so many chances?
thread_cache_size=30  # from 9 since MySQL needs 8 to get started
innodb_io_capacity_max=60000  # from 2000  use that NVME for performance
innodb_io_capacity=30000  # from 200 why stick with a low limit with NVME
key_buffer_size=16M  # from 1G conserve RAM for more useful purpose
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct=90  # from 25 to reduce WARM up time
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=15  # from 25% for your low chg,del,ins need
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1025 to conserve CPU every SECOND
innodb_read_io_threads=64  # from 4 see dba.stackexchange Question 5666
innodb_write_io_threads=64  # from 4 see 9/12/11 RolondaMySQLDBA info
```

please review profile, Network Profile for contact info, including Skype ID and get in touch.

Comment: Thank you, have tested it but it make all Querys slower by 20 to 200%. Will later try to find out which setting exactly make it slower. Anyway I have the feel that my query has some Issue and that the Index even is reported by EXPLAIN is not touched the right way.

Comment: Please post your EXPLAIN result, SHOW CREATE TABLE mp; and SHOW INDEX FROM mp;  please.   Also, EXPLAIN your query; immediately followed by SHOW WARNINGS; in the same session will show you how the OPTIMIZED code was sent to MySQ for processing.  I may have overdriven your NVME at 60000 and 30000 in the io_capacities, drop them to 20000 and 10000, please and run the query twice.  Second time should have buffers fully loaded.  You actually had only about 5G data in the pool on last Global Status.  You might want to try 8G innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Comment: Back to the old rule, change ONLY ONE item, and run test two or three times   Very time consuming with SERVICE stop/starts.

Comment: I have posted all information into my questions. Will soon try one by one config change.

Comment: @nenad007 Could we Skype for 5 minutes?  view profile, Network Profile, for contact info, including Skype ID.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MySQL GIS is always slow. But you're telling me 3 seconds without ORDER BY DISTANCE is slow in a table with 10 million rows? Consider

1. Using this method to [build the points](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/213813/2639)
2. Building the bounding the box with WKT so you have something simplified. I have no idea how this would help, but it's MySQL!
3. Rather than doing `ST_Distance() < upperlimit`, consider doing `ST_Buffer( polygon, upperlimit )`, and using that in your call to `ST_Contains`
4. Consider moving to PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and using `ST_DWithin(geom,geom,upperlimit)`. PostGIS has superior indexing. It can actually do this whole thing on an index [because it supports KNN.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/214354/2639)

Comment: Thank you, I have tried all (except 4) but no change so far. I will sit today one day more on it and hope to find a way. My hope was coming from this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/poor-performance-when-using-spatial-indexes-in-mysql (tried too) where someone was able to got on similiar data set the results in 33ms. When I give up on it, I will put elasticsearch into the stack this should solve but had hope MySQL 8 can handle this.

Comment: You could present data, and schema, and selectivity -- something to actually assist other in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

**Side issues**

Use ascii for hex values such as hashes.

Pack hex hashes into binary:

```
hash_id BINARY(16)
HEX(hash_id)   -- when reading
hash_id = UNHEX(...) -- when writing
```

Get rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT id` and just use hash_id.

Better would be to get rid of the hash -- if the data grows too large to fit in RAM, it will become I/O-bound.

**Faster algorithm**

(Although the primary Question is about GIS, the the secondary question is about speeding up "find nearest".)

For the equivalent of `LIMIT 50`, the following algorithm will probably touch less than 200 rows (and calculate Great Circle distances for only those).  (Better than 79,901?)

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng (code included)

**Analysis of VARIABLES/STATUS**

It seems like you have not run much yet.  Hence, there is not much much to say here:

**Observations:**

- Version: 8.0.12
- 16 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 05:49:58; some GLOBAL STATUS values may not be meaningful yet.
- Are you sure this was a SHOW GLOBAL STATUS ?
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

```
key_buffer_size = 50M
long_query_time = 2
```

Turn on the slowlog so you can identify slow queries.

**Details and other observations:**

`( (key_buffer_size - 1.2 * Key_blocks_used * 1024) / _ram ) = (1024M - 1.2 * 16 * 1024) / 16384M = 6.2%` -- Percent of RAM wasted in key_buffer.
-- Decrease key_buffer_size.

`( Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size ) = 16 * 1024 / 1024M = 0.00%` -- Percent of key_buffer used. High-water-mark.
-- Lower key_buffer_size to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

`( table_open_cache ) = 4,000` -- Number of table descriptors to cache 
-- Several hundred is usually good.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 443,594 / 786432 = 56.4%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size is bigger than necessary?

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 87,040 / (20998 / 3600) / 2 / 512M = 1.4e-5` -- Ratio 
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 20,998 / 60 * 512M / 87040 = 2.16e+6` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size. (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( join_buffer_size / _ram ) = 262,144 / 16384M = 0.00%` -- 0-N per thread. May speed up JOINs (better to fix queries/indexes) (all engines) Used for index scan, range index scan, full table scan, each full JOIN, etc.
-- If large, decrease join_buffer_size to avoid memory pressure. Suggest less than 1% of RAM. If small, increase to 0.01% of RAM to improve some queries.

`( query_prealloc_size / _ram ) = 8,192 / 16384M = 0.00%` -- For parsing. Pct of RAM

`( query_alloc_block_size / _ram ) = 8,192 / 16384M = 0.00%` -- For parsing. Pct of RAM

`( net_buffer_length / max_allowed_packet ) = 16,384 / 64M = 0.02%`

`( (Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions ) = (7 + 7) / 698 = 2.0%` -- Naughty framework -- spending a lot of effort rediscovering the schema.
-- Complain to the 3rd party vendor.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (0 + 20 + 0 + 0) / 0 = INF` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 96 / 355 = 27.0%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( expire_logs_days ) = 0` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin = OFF)

`( slave_pending_jobs_size_max / max_allowed_packet ) = 128M / 64M = 2` -- For parallel slave threads
-- slave_pending_jobs_size_max must not be less than max_allowed_packet

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query. 
-- Suggest 2

`( back_log / max_connections ) = 151 / 151 = 100.0%`

`( Threads_created / Connections ) = 4 / 214 = 1.9%` -- Rapidity of process creation 
-- Increase thread_cache_size (non-Windows)

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_create_db = 0.17 /HR
Com_drop_db = 0.34 /HR
Com_show_profiles = 1.9 /HR
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 0.365
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free = 443,594
Select_range / Com_select = 33.2%
Ssl_session_cache_size = 128
innodb_purge_threads = 4
innodb_undo_tablespaces = 2
max_error_count = 1,024
max_length_for_sort_data = 4,096
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size = 1.05e+6
slave_pending_jobs_size_max = 128MB
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Ssl_session_cache_mode = SERVER
default_authentication_plugin = caching_sha2_password
event_scheduler = ON
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = ON
ft_boolean_syntax = + -><()~*:&
have_query_cache = NO
have_ssl = YES
have_symlink = DISABLED
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup = ON
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_undo_log_truncate = ON
log_syslog = ON
master_info_repository = TABLE
optimizer_trace = enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features = greedy_search=on, range_optimizer=on, dynamic_range=on, repeated_subselect=on
relay_log_info_repository = TABLE
slave_rows_search_algorithms = INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN
ssl_ca = ca.pem
ssl_cert = server-cert.pem
ssl_key = server-key.pem
```

Comment: +1 for the side issue. -1 because it's not clear how the bottom code is at all a better solution. It seems worse in every way. Even as given -- `LIMIT 50`, that code seems worse; but, the problem is finding the 50 *nearest* which that code does nothing (that I can see) to resolve. Pushing people away from GIS on a GIS problem should be explained. That blog says nothing of GIS -- it almost seems like it predates GIS in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by adding an additional condition to my WHERE clause, thereby reducing the number of rows it needs to examine. Depending on your application, you may or may not be able to use the same qualifier I did, but for me any time i'm looking at waypoints inside a polygon, i know what city the polygon is in, so i added WHERE city = XXX.

Here is my BEFORE query which took 2.55 seconds

```
mysql> select listingid FROM property p left join geocodes g on p.listingid=g.mls where st_within(point(g.lat,g.lon),  ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((26.404844904956107 -80.06515801164369, 26.404907366957104 -80.0682586452649, 26.40564729885774 -80.06828010293702, 26.405642494120446 -80.06509900304536, 26.404844904956107 -80.06515801164369))'));
+-----------+
| listingid |
+-----------+
| R10802616 |
| R10798568 |
| R10819043 |
+-----------+
3 rows in set (2.55 sec)
```

compared to the new query which is now 0.00 seconds

```
mysql> select listingid FROM property p FORCE INDEX(city) left join geocodes g on p.listingid=g.mls where city = 'Highland Beach' AND st_within(point(g.lat,g.lon),  ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((26.404844904
04907366957104 -80.0682586452649, 26.40564729885774 -80.06828010293702, 26.405642494120446 -80.06509900304536, 26.404844904956107 -80.06515801164369))'));
+-----------+
| listingid |
+-----------+
| R10802616 |
| R10798568 |
| R10819043 |
+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the table has a city column.

Comment: Understood, but it could probably be added, if not City, then some other qualifier to reduce the dataset from 10M down to something it can traverse more quickly.