# How do you create a Geographic Point with MariaDB and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, spatial, floating-point

PostGIS provides a simple cast to construct a `geography` type from floating point lat, and long

```
SELECT ST_Point(1,2)::geography;     -- standard version (MM) less precision
SELECT ST_MakePoint(1,2)::geography; -- PostGIS version makes 2d, 3dz, 4d
```

However, despite the docs in MySQL clearly telling there is a difference between Cartesian and geodetic points, I can't find out how to construct a geography cord in MySQL or MariaDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MySQL

In MySQL 8+, the point is constructed the same way and whether or not it's geographic (geodetic) or geometric (carestian) is **a function of the SRID** and the `POINT` has the same type. So you'll want to use,

```
SELECT ST_SRID(Point(1,2), 4326);
```

You can set the SRID with [`ST_SRID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-general-property-functions.html#function_st-srid)

## MariaDB

With MariaDB you're SOL. MariaDB still lacks the form that takes a second argument to set the SRID.

See also

- [*How do I create a point with an SRID in MySQL?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/213813/2639)